# How to acces projectstage within a filter

Tags: jsf, servlet-filters

Using a filter for authentication I do not want to login each time during development stage and I do not want to outcomment the filter during development I thought about using the project-stage to only authenticate in production mode.

How can the projectstage be retrieved in a filter since `FacesContext` is not available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's definied as `<context-param>` in `web.xml` the usual way, then you could obtain it in the filter's `init()` as follows:

```
private boolean development;

@Override
public void init(FilterConfig config) {
    development = "Development".equals(config.getServletContext().getInitParameter("javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE"));
}

// ...
```

Comment: Thanks. I would further remove `"javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE"` with the constant `ProjectStage.PROJECT_STAGE_PARAM_NAME`. For more flexibility I will create the enum `ProjectStage` from the string if present.